# Instantaneous velocity

Tags: angularjs, opengl, rotation, velocity

I'm developing a physically based billiard simulator in openGL. In order to calculate the instantaneous rotation axis of each ball in each frame, i.have acess to his instaneous spin velocity  in x, y and z axis. My question is how can i, from those 3 values, calculate the instantaneous rotation axis and the value of the spin among this axis?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's not a unique solution. Rotations are not commutative. Consider this example: First X-axis rotation and later Y-axis rotation versus the other order:

[image]

**You have six possible results**, depending on the order: xyz, yxz, xzy, zxy, etc.

Also, let's say you have an order, e.g. x-y-z. Then you can compose the final matrix by multiplying each rotation matrix: Rf= Rz·Ry·Rx (for the example order). You can determine axis and angle for this final matrix (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Conversion_from_and_to_axis-angle) ... for what? To build a rotation matrix you had in advance?

OK. Let's suppose you did all those calculations and you have axis and angle. Now you have to build the rotation matrix, which you can see in the link above that requires a lot of calculations. Is it worth the effort compared to matrix multiplication?

Comment: After some thought i finally get a solution: from the instaneous angular velocity among x, y and z axis from a given frame, i create my.own rotation matrix using for the axis the vector given by wx i + wy j + wz k. The angle for this.rotation is determined by multiplicating the length of.this vector by the time of a frame (1/FPS).

Comment: Then this rotation matrix is left multiplicated with the rotation matrix in the anterior frame (this matrix acumulate the rotations). So what im doing is acumulate the rotation since t=0. With this solution, I came up with realistic results concerning each ball rotations. Thank you for your answer